# Deduping's "No of contacts to find matches for" field definition

Tags: duplicate-contacts

When you go to "Use Rule" on the "Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts" page, you get a new page that has 2 fields, one called "Select Group" and the other called "No of contacts to find matches for" with a default value of 3.  What is this second field and how does it work?  The documentation I've found so far doesn't include it.

I'm on wordpress 4.7.3 and civicrm 4.7.18.

Thanks,
Ruth

Answer (score 1):

[image: Find and Merge Duplicate Contact Screenshot]

I'm on the same version and this is the view that I'm seeing. Haven't seen what you are referring to...

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about our releases - they're actually WP 4.7.4 and Civi 4.7.16.  Sorry for confusion.  I'll add a screenshot when I figure out how to do it.

Comment: looking on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1 i see no field other than as per this Answer.